# Moving element from left to right corner, if another element is moved to the upper left corner

Tags: jquery, css

I've got an element which is positioned on the upper left corner of the parent element. If another element will be moved onto this element, it should be moved to the upper right corner. If it moves out of that 'target'-area, it should be set back to the upper left corner.

So this is what I did:

```
var css = (top <= 60 && left <= 120) ? { left: 'initial', right: '10px' } : { right: 'initial', left: '10px' };

$target.fadeOut(100, function() {
    $target.css(css).fadeIn(100);
});
```

If the element is moved to the upper left corner (top <=60 and left <=120), new css attribute will be set. The 'old' element gets faded out and the 'new' element is faded in.

My problem is, that this code will be used with every movement of the element. That's why the target id blinking while the element is moved. I need to do that just, if the position is changed. So only if the element is moved in the upper left area, there should be the fading - not (like it is now) on every movement.

**My solution**

```
if (top <= 60 && left <= 120) {
    changed  = (position == 'left') ? true : false;
    position = 'right';
    css      = { left: 'initial', right: '10px' };
}
else {
    changed  = (position == 'right') ? true : false;
    position = 'left';
    css      = { right: 'initial', left: '10px' };
}

if (changed) {
    $target.fadeOut(100, function() {
        $target.css(css).fadeIn(100);
    });
}
```

Maybe this can be optimized...